Can you opt out of Next.js 14 cache for static sites e.g. output: "export"?
Running next build with output: "export" caches the API calls, meaning any changes do not appear in the resulting static files. Is there any way to disable the caching, or get new data when running the build?
setup:

app router
next 14
config: output: "export"
command: next build

issue:

content generated in out folder is stale


According to Next.js Docs, you may use SWR

1. Do you have API routes written in api folder ? 2. Do you want data to refresh by calling API every time page is opened or just get data once during build & never again ?

@Beast80K API calls are going to external resources for the content. I want the data refresh on each build and never again, ideally.

Problem :

Is there any way to disable the caching, or get new data when running the build?

Possible Cause :

By default, Next.js automatically caches the returned values of fetch in the Data Cache on the server.

Possible Solution :
Set the cache option for individual fetch requests to 'no-store' :
fetch('https://...', { cache: 'no-store' }) 


Set Route Segment Config Options in your layout.tsx/js or page.tsx/js or route.ts/js (add this line at top of the file) :
export const fetchCache = 'force-no-store'

Please Read :

Opting out of Data Caching : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#opting-out-of-data-caching
Individual fetch Requests : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#individual-fetch-requests
Route Segment Config : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#options
fetchCache : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#fetchcache


If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)

